# Wordress debug log is not working

Tags: debug, wp-debug

I have tried all recommendations from here but none solves my issue.
I have a couple of wordpress installations on a local machine running Win 7 and wamp 2.4 and none of them writes in the debug.log file or even display the errors in the page.

I have set the following in the wp-config.php:

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);
```

I have manually created an empty file named debug.log in the wp-content directory with full permissions for everyone.

My php.ini settings are:

```
error_reporting = E_ALL
display_errors = On
display_startup_errors = On
log_errors = on
log_errors_max_len = 1024
ignore_repeated_errors = Off
track_errors = On
html_errors = On
error_log = "C:/wamp/logs/php_error.log"
```

The only way to debug is to use one of the available plugins but they are useless when I'm getting the white screen.

Comment: Check: `C:/wamp/logs/php_error.log` and try the example config in the [Debugging Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress).  May I also recommend [Aptana Studio 3](http://aptana.com/products/studio3) to help debug your PHP.

Comment: My config is exactly like the recommended in Codex and both logs, xamp's php_error.log and wp's debug.log are empty. Will try Aptana.

Comment: Taking a look at the [gist: paranoia-config.php](https://gist.github.com/franz-josef-kaiser/4063197) by @kaiser might give you some additional information.

Comment: Do you see errors with `WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY` enabled? What does `ini_get('error_log')` contain after load (at `init` or later)?